# How to add customSearch component in admin products grid in Magento 2?

Tags: admin, search, magento-2.2.5, product-grid

I have to add custom "Search by Keyword" functionality for the products grid in Magento 2. I have to add one text field there for search. when I type it give me search result suggestion.

[image]

By default, Magento 2 provide "Search by Keyword" functionality for orders but not for products.